# Как правильно открыть окно с формой и сюда же подставить значение?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой код:

```
(function aaa(){

var a = window.open("https://site.ru/q/1919", "hello", "width=1500,height=1000");

jQuery(".form--text").val("hello");

}())
```

По идею должен был открыться окно и подставиться значение "hello" в форму textarea.

Окно у меня открывается, но значение в форму textarea не подставляется.

Синтаксических ошибок нет, как исправить так, чтобы подставился?

Answer (score 4):

Всякие запреты по безопасности не дают разгуляться.
Должен совпадать **протокол**, **хостнейм** и **порт**.
С адреса `https://some.org:1024/how_are_you_dude?` можно открыть любые окна, но доступ к содержимому (`document`, например) будет только у `https://some.org:1024/all_what_you_want/`.

Остальные получат ошибку:

> DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://child_window.host" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Если доступ есть, то легко:

```
console.info(location.origin); // http://ru.stackoverflow.com
let w = window.open("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1919", "hello", "width=1500,height=1000");
w.document.querySelector('.form--text').value = 'hello';
```

---

Если доступа нет, попробуйте решить проблему через фреймы, `iFrame.contentWindow.postMessage` и `window.addEventListener('message', fn);` (в окне фрейма).
Ну или передавайте параметры в URI, как предложил @CostaRaf.

Comment: Что-то не хочет подставлять, т.е. подставляет только на текущее окно. Может еще фокус нужно как-нибудь сделать на новое окно?

Comment: А что не работает? Покажите код. Если система защиты умиротворена, доступ должен быть.

Comment: К примеру из текущей страницы `http://ru.stackoverflow.com` хотим заполнить заголовок (подставим ваш код):

`let w = window.open("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", "hello", "width=1500,height=1000");
w.document.querySelector('input#title').value = 'hello';`

Окно открывается, но не подставляет значение + выдает ошибку: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null(…)`

Это из-за доступа или из-за синтаксиса? Как можно решить ошибку выше?

Comment: 1) `#title`. 2) Работает всё, ошибка говорит о том, что элемент не найден. Почему - не знаю как именно вы запускали, ибо у меня работает (хром, лиса). Покажите весь ваш код.

Comment: Из текущей страницы (на которой сейчас обсуждаем) подставил код, который указал выше (`let w = window.open("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", "hello", "width=1500,height=1000"); w.document.querySelector('input#title').value = 'hello';`) через инструмент разработчика хрома (через лису тоже пробовал) и все, это и есть весь код

Comment: Ну так надо дождаться когда `DOM` загрузиться. `w = window.open("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", "hello", "width=1500,height=1000"); w.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {console.info(w.document.querySelector('#title'));w.document.querySelector('#title').value = 'hello';});` - тогда так.

Answer (score 1):

Выбора не много... 
Попробуйте передать значение в textarea через параметр url

```
var a = window.open("https://site.ru/q/1919?param=hello", "hello", "width=1500,height=1000");
```

и перехватить его на стороне открывающегося окна :

```
var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(7))
$(".test1").html(sPageURL);
```